# How to connect to (& edit) PostgreSQL database using ArcGIS Desktop without ArcSDE?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, postgresql

After trying in vein to get [spatialkit](http://www.st-links.com/Pages/default.aspx) and zgis working with my postgresql database in arcgis 9.3 and 10 , I was wondering if anyone has had any luck with these products.

My postgresql database has been serving geospatial data for 2 years through geoserver and can be edited in quantum gis fine....so why not in ArcGIS?

Does anyone have any other recipes for using postgresql data with arcgis but WITHOUT ArcSDE?

Comment: Did some beta testing for ziggis (postgis editing) 18/24 months ago was editing but posting back to postgis was erogenous at the time. Though potentially a good tool. Demo is here still http://code.google.com/p/ziggis/downloads/detail?name=zigGIS-2.0.3-Launch-Demo.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: "zigGIS has officially reached its end-of-life" (Wed, 3 Aug 2011)- link [here](http://groups.google.com/group/ziggis/browse_thread/thread/14ae8a351564de9e)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ArcGIS 10 and you don't need to edit, you can use a query layer:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_a_query_layer/00s500000027000000/

(Not my video): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsMEwdwH6Ts

your editing comment reminds me of a post by [Bill Dollins](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/146/bill-dollins)--you might want to check out pgmap:
http://blog.geomusings.com/2011/08/09/taking-a-look-at-pgmap/

Comment: Editing would be nice!

Comment: I was able to edit with PgMap/SpatialKit without issue. It actually worked quite well with the intrinsic editing tools of ArcGIS.

Answer (score 0):

yep, that's exactly what I am doing right now, but I am using geoserver as well. Essentially I am making a custom scripting module for my toolbox and using the arcpy package, so you would have to know a bit of python maybe. From the arcpy package I am using the QuickExport function. In order to get the function's parameters I am using the Quick Export Interoperability tool under Arcmap and you can specify Postgres for that. The only thing is, you have to make sure your parameters are set correctly, so you should first try the quick export manually and read the output dialog before simply inputting parameters to the script.

I am also using psycopg2 to establish a connection to the database and then using the postgres library for some sql queries.

Oh and you should also probably write the script in an ide like idle or komodo as opposed to using arcmap's built in command line for python.

Comment: Interesting post. I have done a little scripting in Python in idle but do not have the data-interoperability extention...is this what you meant? Can you actually edit your postgis data with the arcgis editing tools?

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem.

My approach is to view the PostGIS data not directly in ArcGIS, but to export the data into shapefiles which are then used to view and edit the data in ArcGIS.

The main concern with this approach is synchronizing between the shapefiles and PostGIS. For this I'm using a background thread which checks if there are changes in the database on a regular basis (every 5 seconds) and if this is the case, the shapefiles are generated and exchanged.
For the other direction I am writing an editor extension which handles editor events, queues them internally and after the user saved the editor session, the changes are committed to the database.

I know it may sound a little bit crazy, but it was the best idea I had - because I had the same problems with zigGis and SpatialKit, Query Layers' missing edit possibility and the need to operate without ArcSDE...